# Visual Studio Code stopped finding some libraries

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Well, a few hours ago I posted this:

"BeautifulSoup suddenly stopped working in my computer, despite the fact I have been using it no problem a couple days ago. I tried uninstalling it and re-installing but to no avail. Is anybody aware of this issue?

[Proof of my bsp version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp06r.png)

I am in Windows btw"

And just now I tried to import numpy and got the same mistake. I have already used both libraries when I changed my IDE to VSC, I don't know what may have changed.
I tried out opening a cmd, running py there and importing both modules and it works just fine. Might it be a problem with environment variables?

Comment: are you running in venv? if so install in venv as well. system install doesn't apply in the environment

Comment: How do you try import it?

Comment: I import it like this "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsp"

Comment: No, I am not running in venv, the running conditions are exactly the same ones as they were when the module was working

Comment: Try to run in venv. Because it can directly set to the path for your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, apparently my system installed a newer Python version in a different directory, so VSC got de-configured, I just had to select which Python interpreter I needed to use